# Detect the type of parameter passed in class constructor

Tags: c#, class, types, constructor, parameter-passing

I want the constructor of a class to be able to pass two types of parameters, then inside the method do some stuff based on the type of the parameter. the types would be `double` and `String[]`. the class and its constructor is something similar to:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass (Type par /* the syntax here is my issue */ )
    {
        if (Type.GetType(par) == String[])
        {  
            /// Do the stuff
        }

        if (Type.GetType(par) == double)
        {  
            /// Do another stuff 
        }
}
```

and the class would be instantiated on another class this way:

```
double d;
String[] a;

new MyClass(d);    /// or new MyClass(a);
```

Comment: Just overload the constructor and call an initialization method from both.

Comment: I suspect you want `if (type == typeof(string[]))`... you only want the type, right, not an *instance* of the type?

Comment: @Aggressor Thanks. It's the right way

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you're right but could you please explain a little more?

Comment: Well what more explanation do you need? (It's not clear whether you really only need to do things by type, or whether you should actually be taking *instances* of the type...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create two constructors. One for each type.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass (Double d)
   {
        //stuff
   }

   public MyClass(String[] s)
   {
       //other stuff
   }
}
```

Also, i recommend you read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following - but I wouldn't recommend it. Separate constructors (as shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31766238/477420) ) would be simpler and much better from type safety point of view.

```
public MyClass(object par)
{

    if (par.GetType() == typeof(double))
    {
        // do double stuff
    }
    if (par.GetType() == typeof(string))
    {
        // do string stuff
    }
    else
    {
       // unexpected - fail somehow, i.e. throw ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What if someone use it with any other type?

Comment: That's why this is a BAD idea. why would you want them to be able to send anything? using if ... else if .. finally the last else would be what to do if you have no idea what the object is. But if you just want doubles or strings.. 2 constructors is better

Comment: The question is not *what would happen if they passed some other type*, the question is *what do **you** want to happen*. That is why overloaded constructors are a much better solution. They signal what is allowed and allows you to write concise code.

Comment: mentioning an alternative way and exposing its pros & cons in comments was helpful. thanks.

Comment: Side note: `par.GetType() == typeof(double)` could be shortened to `par is double`. A little neater!